# 4 Diagonal lines in the background not showing up or causing page displacement on refresh

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add four diagonal lines to the background of my webpage, each with a width of 60% - 70% of the viewport. However, I'm facing two issues:

1. The diagonal lines are not showing up on the page.
2. Every time I refresh the page, it causes a displacement and pushes the content down to the next page.

I've tried using the following CSS code for the diagonal lines:

```css
.current-stats {
  height: 80vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
}

.stripes-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.rec-2 {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
  transform: rotate(-15deg) scaleX(0);
}

@keyframes appearRight {
  to {
    transform: rotate(-15deg) scaleX(1);
  }
}

.rec-2:nth-of-type(1) {
  border-bottom: 30px solid #1DCDFE;
  animation: appearRight 1s linear both;
}

.rec-2:nth-of-type(2) {
  border-bottom: 30px solid #11FFC4;
  animation: appearRight 1.2s linear both;
}

.rec-2:nth-of-type(3) {
  border-bottom: 30px solid #21D0B2;
  animation: appearRight 1.4s linear both;
}

.rec-2:nth-of-type(4) {
  border-bottom: 30px solid #2F455C;
  animation: appearRight 1.6s linear both;
}

.frame2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 2%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 550px;
  background: #2F455C;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.current-stats img {
  position: relative;
  right: 12%;
  filter: brightness(70%) drop-shadow(0 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.352));
  width: 650px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.current {
  font-size: 48px;
  width: 20%;
  transform: rotate(10deg);
  font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
  top: 0px;
  left: 57%;
  text-align: center;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
}

.pointer2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 35%;
  z-index: 3;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  width: 650px;
}
```

```html
<section class="current-stats">
  <div class="stripes-2">
    <span class="rec-2"></span>
    <span class="rec-2"></span>
    <span class="rec-2"></span>
    <span class="rec-2"></span>
  </div>
  <h2 class="current">Projected Goals</h2>
  <div class="frame2">
    <div class="stats">
      <div class="manage">
        <p><span style="font-size: 3rem;">2.5 mil</span> in assests managed</p>
        <section class="bar-graph bar-graph-vertical bar-graph-two">
          <div class="bar-one bar-container">
            <div class="bar" data-percentage="40%"></div>
            <span class="year">2023</span>
          </div>
          <div class="bar-two bar-container">
            <div class="bar" data-percentage="55%"></div>
            <span class="year">2024</span>
          </div>
          <div class="bar-three bar-container">
            <div class="bar" data-percentage="68%"></div>
            <span class="year">2025</span>
          </div>
          <div class="bar-four bar-container">
            <div class="bar" data-percentage="82%"></div>
            <span class="year">2026</span>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
      <div class="account">
        <ion-icon class="usd" name="logo-usd"></ion-icon>
        <p>Discretionary Investment Accounts</p>
      </div>
      <div class="guidance">
        <p>TRUSTWORTHY GUIDANCE</p>
        <ion-icon class="people" name="people-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <img src="/images/pexels-photo-7641859.jpg">
</section>
```

Can anyone help me understand why the diagonal lines are not showing up and why they cause the page displacement on refresh? Are there any potential conflicts or issues with the CSS code that I'm missing?